# How to make my program faster with Open MPI? My Open MPI program is currently slower than the original, what am I not understanding?

Tags: c++, performance, openmpi

I have written a program for an assignment that cracks passwords using a dictionary attack and am trying to speed it up using Open MPI but my Open MPI version is slower and I am not sure why or what I am not understanding. The encrypted passwords are generated using a salt and a string passed into the unix function 'crypt.'

From what I have learned from looking at my class lecture notes, this is what I have come up with.

main.cc:

```cpp
//****************************************************
// File: main.cc
// Author: Jordan Ward
// Purpose: Crack passwords in the form word+number
// or number+word where number can be at most
// three digits long using
// Open MPI to make it more efficient.
//*****************************************************

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

// Builds the list of encrypted passwords,
// list of dictionary words, and list of salts.
void file_IO(int argc, char *argv[], vector<string> &encPass, vector<string> &words,
            vector<string> &salts);

// Builds the list of possible guesses.
void build_guesses(vector<string> &guesses, vector<string> &words);

// Tries each of the salts with each of
// the strings in the list of guesses to see
// if they match the ecrypted passwords.
void crack(string pass, vector<string> &salts, vector<string> &guesses);

// Broadcasts the vectors to all other processes.
void broadcast_receive(vector<string> &encPass, vector<string> &words,
                       vector<string> &salts, vector<string> &guesses);

// Converts a vector of strings to a vector of chars
vector<char> convert(vector<string> &strings);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<string> encPass;
    vector<string> words;
    vector<string> salts;
    vector<string> guesses;

    int numProcesses;
    int procNum;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcesses);   // Get the number of processes
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procNum);        // Get the process number

    if(procNum == 0) {
        file_IO(argc, argv, encPass, words, salts);
        build_guesses(guesses, words);
    }

    broadcast_receive(encPass, words, salts, guesses, numProcesses, procNum);

    if(procNum != 0) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < encPass.size(); i++) {
            if(i % procNum == 0) {
                size_t del = encPass[i].rfind("$");         // Finds the last "$" in the string
                string pass = encPass[i].substr(del);       // Pass is a substring starting at the last "$"
                crack(pass, salts, guesses);
            }
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}


void file_IO(int argc, char *argv[], vector<string> &encPass, vector<string> &words,
            vector<string> &salts) {

    if(argc < 3) {
        cout << "One or more files were not specified." << endl;
        cout << "Correct format is 'mpiexec a.out file1 file2'" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    ifstream secretPass(argv[1]);
    string singlePass;

    while(getline(secretPass, singlePass)) {
        encPass.push_back(singlePass);
    }

    secretPass.close();

    ifstream dictionary(argv[2]);
    string word;

    while(getline(dictionary, word)) {
        words.push_back(word);
    }

    dictionary.close();

    ifstream salt("salts");
    string s;

    while(getline(salt, s)) {
        salts.push_back(s);
    }

    salt.close();
}

void build_guesses(vector<string> &guesses, vector<string> &words) {
    //one word and one number
    for(size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            guesses.push_back(words[i] + to_string(j));
        }
    }

    //one number and one word
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < words.size(); j++) {
            guesses.push_back(to_string(i) + words[j]);
        }
    }

    //one word and two numbers
    for(size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            for(size_t x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                guesses.push_back(words[i] + to_string(j) + to_string(x));
            }
        }
    }

    //two numbers and one word
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            for(size_t x = 0; x < words.size(); x++) {
                guesses.push_back(to_string(i) + to_string(j) + words[x]);
            }
        }
    }

    //one word and three numbers
    for(size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            for(size_t x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                for(size_t y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                    guesses.push_back(words[i] + to_string(j) + to_string(x) + to_string(y));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //three numbers and one word
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            for(size_t x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                for(size_t y = 0; y < words.size(); y++) {
                    guesses.push_back(to_string(i) + to_string(j) + to_string(x) + words[y]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void crack(string pass, vector<string> &salts, vector<string> &guesses) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < salts.size(); i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < guesses.size(); j++) {
            string ep = crypt(guesses[j].c_str(), salts[i].c_str());

            if(ep.compare(salts[i] + pass) == 0) {
                cout << "Password: " + guesses[j] << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Password not found" << endl;
}

void broadcast_receive(vector<string> &encPass, vector<string> &words,
                       vector<string> &salts, vector<string> &guesses) {

    int buffer[5];

    buffer[0] = encPass.size();
    buffer[1] = words.size();
    buffer[2] = salts.size();
    buffer[3] = guesses.size();

    MPI_Bcast(buffer, 4, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    encPass.resize(buffer[0]);
    words.resize(buffer[1]);
    salts.resize(buffer[2]);
    guesses.resize(buffer[3]);

    vector<char> ep = convert(encPass);
    vector<char> w = convert(words);
    vector<char> s = convert(salts);
    vector<char> g = convert(guesses);

    MPI_Bcast(ep.data(), ep.size(), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(w.data(), w.size(), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(s.data(), s.size(), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(g.data(), g.size(), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

vector<char> convert(vector<string> &strings) {
    vector<char> cstrings;
    cstrings.reserve(strings.size());

    for(string s : strings) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s.c_str()); i++) {
            cstrings.push_back(s.c_str()[i]);
        }
    }

    return cstrings;
}
```

My thought process is:

If process number is 0, read in the files and build the vectors with strings from the files and then build the list of guesses.

Else, receive all the lists and go through each encrypted password and see if any of the salts combined with any of the guesses matches the encrypted password.

What am I not doing correctly or not understanding that is making this slower than the original without the Open MPI code? Original code would just be the same file without the broadcast_receive and convert functions and obviously without the MPI calls in the main function.

I am compiling with `mpic++ -std=c++11 -Wall main.cc -lcrypt` and then running with `mpiexec a.out enc_passwords words` where enc_passwords is a small file with some encrypted passwords generated from the crypt function and words is a small list of words to build the guesses with.

Comment: Anyone please help

Comment: It looks like every process does the same work (except the root, which just exits early).  What division of labor am I missing?

Comment: @DavisHerring I thought I was doing it so that process 0 was building the lists and then sending them to the other processes and then the other processes were doing the password matching. So obviously if that's not what is happening then I am not understanding correctly.

Comment: You’re right, but if you think carefully about what you just said, you’ll see that there’s no opportunity for speedup there (if, as here, the other processes are all identical).

Comment: @DavisHerring So I kind of get what you are saying and I tried adding `if(i % 4 == procNum)` before the lines in the for loop of my main function but that doesn't seem to work either. I am running with `mpiexec -np 4 a.out enc_passwords words`. Do I need to do a `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` after I do the password matching?

Comment: If you have only three workers, `i%4` will not do all the work.  Beyond that, you need to define “doesn’t seem to work”, as in *any* problem report.

Comment: @DavisHerring I have updated my code a bit but for some reason it is throwing a ton of errors. Some say `terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic string` and a lot that say something like `Signal: Abort trap: 6 (6)`

Not sure where or why I would be getting an out of range error though. I double checked my boundaries in my for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question (why isn't MPI "faster"?), you need to ask two questions:

Q: Is the work actually being partitioned to multiple processors, in parallel?

Q: Does the overhead of message passing exceed the actual work you're trying to parallelize?

This should help with both questions:

[OpenMPI FAQ: Performance Tools](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=perftools)

Regarding your follow-on comment, *"...but for some reason it is throwing a ton of errors."*: please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Or simply revert back to the "working" code.

Comment: I just gave up, its due at 11:59 tonight and I have no idea what I'm doing I guess.